# How to print only once from all the parallel processors?

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I'm running a parallel program in Fortran and using MPI. There is an algorithm that is executed by only certain parallel processors which contain a flag. I want to print a statement only once but I couldn't use MPI_Rank = 0 as it might/might not satisfy the IF condition of whether it contains the flag. The parallel processors which contain the flag changes when I change the problem and I want to keep the code generic. Any help? Thank you!

```
 if(diu.eq.1) then
 update_flag = mod(nrevs,update_step + 1)
 if(update_flag .eq. update_step) then
 update_no = nrevs/update_step
 write(*,*) 'In Update loop, Rev =',nrevs,'and phase = ',iiphase,
& 'for', update_no, 'time(s)'
```

Comment: If any processor can execute the "print" ... and if they're all processing independently of each other ... then how can the processor that "prints" signal the other processors to "not print"???

Comment: @Mark - You are right any one. The reason is that this is just a WRITE statement for notification that it is inside the IF loop and takes a lot of space in the log file as the number of processors can be around 100 processors. It has to be sent to a console before the algorithm starts. Can you clarify about steering the computation?

Comment: I have added a preview of my algorithm with print statement in my orignal post, just having one statement that it is inside the IF loop is more than enough for me. The program won't crash and nor will the log file, it's just easy to read the program without repeated same print statements.

Comment: you can use `MPI_Allgather(..., MPI_MIN, ...)` to find the lowest rank that has the flag set. keep it mind `MPI_Allgather()` is a collective operation and must be invoked by **all** the ranks of the communicator, so you have to find the right place to call it so it won't deadlock nor kill your performances.

Comment: I see @GillesGouaillardet has suggested how you might achieve what you want.